# How to update local data after mutation?

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I want to find a better way to update local component state after executing mutation. I'm using svelte-apollo but my question is about basic principles. I have **watchQuery** which get list of items and returns **ObservableQuery** in component.

```
query GetItems($sort: String, $search: String!) {
  items(
    sort: $sort
    where: { name_contains: $search }
  ) {
    id
    name
    item_picture{
      pictures{
        url
        previewUrl
      }
    }
    description
    created_at
  }
}
```

In component I call it:

```svelte
<script>
  $: query = GetItems({
    variables: {
      sort: 'created_at:DESC',
      search
    }
  });
</script>
...
{#each $query.data?.items || [] as item, key (item.id)}
  <div>
    <Item
      deleteItem={dropItem}
      item={item}
      setActiveItem={setActiveItem}
    />
  </div>
{/each}
...
```

And I have `addItem` mutation.

```
mutation addItem($name: String!, $description: String) {
  createItem(
    input: { data: { name: $name, description: $description } }
  ) {
    item {
      name
      description
    }
  }
}
```

I just simply want to update local state and add new item to an observable query result after **addItem** mutation, without using refetchQueries (because I don't want to get all list by network when I just added one item).
I seen this item in cache but my view is not updated.

[image]

P.S. If you have similar problems and some ways to solve it, be glad to see some cases from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in this case, you could use the `cache.modify` function to modify the cache directly if you’re looking to skip the network request from refetchQueries. Would that work for your use case? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#making-all-other-cache-updates

If you don’t mind the network request, I like using `cache.evict` to evict the data in the cache that I know changed personally. I prefer that to `refetchQueries` in most cases because it refetches all queries that used that piece of data, not just the queries I specify.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it today.

Comment: What exactly return hook *useMutation* from this article? 
const [addTodo] = useMutation(ADD_TODO, {
    update(cache, { data: { addTodo } })
I mean *addTodo *. Is this expected mutation response?